# First ansible playbook help (Error Checking)

Tags: ansible

I am writing my first Ansible playbook and I am a bit lost, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Here is my code:

```
    ---

- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: check /var/log/messages
      shell: "cat /var/log/messages | grep error | mailx -r xxx@xxx.com xxx@gmail.com"
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: check /var/log/secure
      shell: "cat /var/log/secure | grep denied | mailx -r xxx@xxx.com xxx@gmail.com"
      ignore_errors: yes
```

I am getting a separate email for each server, and even when there is nothing, I get a blank one. I read some stuff about handlers, would one of those be good to say if the output is null, dont do anything.

Comment: You can to use the mail module instead of using shell

Answer (score 0):

you can use following snippet. Worked on ansible 2.7+ .

What is doing?

1. first task is running shell command and storing output in results. "results" is standard variable provided by ansible. you can refer return values in ansible here. [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)
2. second task will be : Based on results is empty or not, it will send output over mail

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: check /var/log/messages
      shell: "cat /var/log/messages | grep error"
      register: results
      ignore_errors: yes

   - name: Send mail
     shell: " echo {{ results.stdout }} | mailx -r xxx@xxx.com xxx@gmail.com"
     when: result.stdout == ""
```